# IIf in 2 data sets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have 2 data sets in my project. 1 data set returns a String Column.
Like below

### Name

Praveen
Thomas
Joseph

Another data set also returns a string column like below

### CMDBNetBiosName

Praveen
Joseph

I need to compare both the columns in data sets and need to return Yes in another column if both are same, return No if both are not same. I was trying to use below IIF expression for this but receiving errors.

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!Name.Value) = Sum(Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value,"DataSet2"),"Yes","No")
```

I'm pretty new to SSRS. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the IIF expression you are trying? Where are you using that expression? It is hard to guess what the root of the problem is with that very short description.

Comment: I'm using below expression to compare Name field and CMDBnetBios field (which is from different dataset- dataset2)... if both are same return Yes if not return No.

=IIf(Sum(Fields!Name.Value) = Sum(Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value,"DataSet2"),"Yes","No")   @alejandrozuleta

Comment: actually both fields returns strings not integers... but some how to avoid errors kept Sum expression in it... please ignore it @alejandrozuleta

Comment: Both datasets return only one row?

Comment: yes both datasets return only one row @alejandrozuleta

Comment: oops both datasets return only one column... many rows will be there @alejandrozuleta

Comment: Which row is going to be compared? Where are you using the expression in a tablix? could you edit your question include a sample of both datasets?

Comment: yeah updated it... Could you please kindly check that now once @alejandrozuleta

Comment: If you need to compare it row by row you will need to add a key to relate both datasets, you can add a row number column in each dataset and use  SSRS Lookup function. Also note you can't iterate through rows in two datasets at the same time.

Comment: I'm new to SSRS... could you please help me... if this lookup function is making some sense

=Lookup(Fields!Name.Value, Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value, Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value, "DataSet1")

but this function is not able to return Yes/No... it could only return the name if it is existing... how to return Yes/No @alejandrozuleta

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
=IIF(
ISNOTHING(
  Lookup(
    Fields!Name.Value,Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value, Fields!CMDBNetBios.Value, "DataSet2")),
"No","Yes")
```

This expressions works like this: if you have a tablix set to `DataSet1` you can iterate over each row in it and look up the `Name` field in the `DataSet2`, if the Name is present in **any** `CMDBNetBiosName` row it returns `Yes` otherwise `No`.

Hope it helps.